# C++ download progress report algorithm

Tags: c++, performance

I have an application (Qt but that is not really important) which is downloading several files and I want to notify the user about the progress. The c++ app runs on a different machine and progress reports are sent over network (protocoll does not matter here). I do not want to sent for each data receival a message over the network but only in defined intervalls e.g. every 5% (so 0%, 5%, 10%).

Basically I have it like this right now:

```
void Downloader::OnUpdateDownloadProgress(int downloaded_bytes)
{
    m_files_downloaded_size += downloaded_bytes;

    int perc_download = (int) ((m_files_downloaded_size /  m_files_total_size)*100);

    if(m_percentage_buffer > LocalConfig::getDownloadReportSteps() || m_files_downloaded_size == m_files_total_size){
        emit sigDownloadProgress(DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS, perc_download);
        m_percentage_buffer = 0;
    }else{
        m_percentage_buffer +=  (downloaded_bytes /  m_files_total_size) * 100;
    }

}
```

Which means that for each data receival triggering this slot I need to perform:

greater comparison, addition , division, multiplication

I know that I could at least skimp on the multiplication by storing a float in the settings and comparing to that. Other than that are there any ways to get this more performant or did I do good on my first try implementing?

Comment: I believe, network communication and signal emitting are much slower than a few _greater comparison, addition , division, multiplication_. Hence, I wouldn't concern too much about this. I guess, there's not much to gain here.

Comment: Btw. if `m_files_downloaded_size` and `m_files_total_size` are integral values, then you would get always 0 until former is not lower than latter. In this case, the formula should be changed to `m_files_downloaded_size * 100 / m_files_total_size`. (At least, using this, you could do it with integral values instead of floating point.)

Comment: @Scheff I guess from an overall perspective you are right, those would be micro improvements. But I was interested to see if I there was another way to implement the algorithm more efficiently just from a general knowledge perspective not because I desperately need it.

Comment: Concerning my 2nd comment: In the past, integer arithmetic was considered faster than floating point arithmetic. Nowadays, that's surely still true for most of embedded CPUs (some of them even don't have an FPU to lower costs and energy consumption) but even on Intels i[357] that might still be true.